# Storing cookie with SameSite option as `Any kind of connection`

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, cookies

Im working on a .NetCore MVC project.
As the title suggests my goal is to store a cookie that will eventually be accessible through an iframe.

In order to achieve that this is what I did -

Startup.cs -

```
            app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
            {
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
            });
```

Using the actual CookieOption class -

```
        public void SetCookie(string key, string value, int? expireTime, HttpResponse Response)
        {
            CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
            //allow cross-site cookies for iframes
            option.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;

            if (expireTime.HasValue)
                option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expireTime.Value);
            else
                option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(10);
            Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, option);
        }
```

Doing the above It seems like it doesn't always work as intended.
Iv'e tested lots of browsers both desktop and mobile.
Just found out that sometimes the cookie is stored successfully like so -

```
Send for:
   Any kind of connection

Accessible to script:
   Yes
```

And sometimes on the same exact chrome version just a different computer its stored like so -

```
Send for:
   Same-site connections only

Accessible to script:
   Yes
```

Which basically means it won't be accessible using iframes.
The problem isn't a specific computer issue as I was managed to duplicate the problem on 3 different computers running the same chrome version which works fine on other computers.

The example above was produced using this chrome version (last version):
Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Anyone have an idea how can I overcome that ? gotta make sure cookies will always be accessible using an iframe.

Thanks!

**Edit** - Attempt with Secure and HttpOnly flag
So iv'e adjusted my code to set the HttpOnly and the Secure flags to true.
The computers that usually worked fine had this cookie settings -

```
Send for
    Secure connections only
Accessible to script
    No (HttpOnly)
```

And it works fine with iframe.

The computer which didn't work before had this cookie settings -

```
Send for
    Secure same-site connections only
Accessible to script
    No (HttpOnly)
```

Which obviously didn't work with an iframe...

Just updating of another approach that didn't work.

**Edit 2** - Using fiddler to intercept the cookies response:

So using fiddler to read the cookie this is what it looks like -

```
    Set-Cookie: __cfduid={randomvaluehere}; expires=Fri, 24-Apr-20 17:37:48 GMT; path=/; domain=.domain.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax

    Set-Cookie: mycookie=mycookievalue; expires=Fri, 24 Apr 2020 17:37:49 GMT; path=/; secure; httponly
```

So seems like the response is storing a cookie with is SameSite=Lax on the apex of the domain, which I don't care about.
I work on a sub-domain which is the second set-cookie that is shown above.
Looks like SameSite=None isn't explicitly presented, should it? if so why wouldn't it seeing the code above?
Also reminding you that exactly that works fine for other browsers or other computers with the same chrome version.

The sample above is exactly the same on computer where it worked and in one that it wasn't.

Comment: Does chrome give you any warnings?

Comment: Are these different systems accessing the same server instance? Or is the server running locally for development?

Comment: Its a production server.

So few computers with the same chrome version are accessing the exact same production environment. while for some it works as it should and for some it doesn't...
let me know if there's anything else I can add up.

Comment: Next thing to check is capturing a Fiddler trace to make sure the Set-Cookie response header is the same for each of them.

Comment: Will do it and update, thanks for the idea!

Comment: @Tratcher did what you suggested, please see Edit2 in my post.
Looking into it it seems like the cookie doesn't excplicity mark samesite.none on it, is this how it suppose to be? well it does work on other browsers and on some chrome machines lol. thanks

Comment: That means you are using an outdated version of AspNetCore. SameSite=None support was added in the December patch.

Comment: Oh dam, I'll try to update my aspnetcore version, I'll let you know.
If thats the case, why do the same exact code works on some computers with the same chrome version? O.O

Comment: @Tratcher that indeed fixed the problem, sitll no idea why it works on some computers tho...
If you wish to make post an answer I'll mark it as answered.
Thanks mate

Comment: Chrome has only just started enforcing it, and they're scaling it up gradually.

Comment: FYI if you need to use SameSiteMode.None but updating to netcore 3.1 is too difficult, in netcore 2.2 you can set the SameSite option to '(SameSiteMode)(-1)' as a workaround.